# Как реализовать бинарное дерево поиска?

Tags: c++, c, структуры-данных, дерево, бинарное-дерево

нужно реализовать бинарное дерево поиска, но я не понимаю что записыть в key(ключ)
дата - это заносимые данные(напр числа или чаровские эллементы)
лефт - левая ветка
райт - правая ветка
но нужто то то в этот ключ вписывать(мне объясняли - это что то типа id, но я не понимаю как дальше это все реализовывать)
хелп
вот кусок кода

```
template<typename T, typename K>
class Tree
{
class Node
{
public:
    Node() :data_(0), key(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}; //не факт что я здесь все верно написал
    Node(T d, K k) :data_(d), key(k), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}; //и здесь
    friend Tree;
    //Node(T);
    ~Node();

private:
    T data_;
    K key;
    Tree *left;
    Tree *right;
};
Tree() :root(nullptr) {};
Tree *root;
};
```

Comment: Ключ нужен для нумерации веток, например. Или если надоо два тпа данных в ветке хранить. Если нужно пронумеровать ветки - нужен. Если не нужно такое - можно без ключа. Зависит от поставленой вам задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ключ записываются значения, по которым будет производиться поиск, а в поле данных - сами данные. Например, у вас может быть структура, содержащая сведения о студентах, и вы хотите организовать поиск по фамилии. Тогда ключом будет фамилия, которая возможно хранится как объект символьного массива или стандартного класса std::string, а данными вся структура, описывающая студента, в которой помимо фамилии могут быть такие сведения, как дата рождения, успеваемость, номер группы и т.д.